# Python multithreading - play multiple sine waves simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to generate sine wave noises at a given frequency and duration. I would like this to play simultaneously while using a GUI.

I've created a class that makes use of threading but it doesn't seem to work. I cannot execute code at the same time as invoking the .run() line. For example when running the below code, the print statement executes after the sound has completed.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import threading

class WavePlayerLoop(threading.Thread) :
  """
  A simple class based on PyAudio to play sine wave at certain frequency.
  It's a threading class. You can play audio while your application
  continues to do stuff.
  """

  def __init__(self, freq=440., length=1., volume=0.5):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    self.volume = volume     # range [0.0, 1.0]
    self.fs = 44100          # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
    self.duration = length   # in seconds, may be float
    self.f = freq            # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

  def run(self) :
    """
    Just another name for self.start()
    """
    # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
    self.samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(self.fs*self.duration)*self.f/self.fs)).astype(np.float32)

    # for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
    self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=self.fs,
                    output=True)

    # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
    self.stream.write(self.volume*self.samples)

    self.stream.stop_stream()
    self.stream.close()

    self.p.terminate()

s = WavePlayerLoop(freq=440., length=10., volume=0.5)
s.run()
print 'this should print while there is a beep sound'
```

What do I need to do to allow this sound to play simultaneously while other code can execute?

Comment: *How* doesn't it seem to work? Please [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the main description!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have got it fully right. Following test code is working perfectly fine with your code.

```
objs = []
number_of_threads = 10

print 'Creating thread objects'
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    objs.append(WavePlayerLoop(freq=440 * i, length=10., volume=0.1 * i))

print 'Starting thread objects'
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    objs[i].start()

print 'Waiting for threads to finish'
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    objs[i].join()

print ('Finishing program')
```

Comment: So I had to do .start() instead of .run()? Looks like I didn't read into the threading documentation closely enough... Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up and Python-3-ified version that might be helpful for the contemporary seeker

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import threading

class WavePlayerLoop(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, freq=440., volume=0.5, duration=1.):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.volume = volume     # range [0.0, 1.0]
        self.fs = 44100          # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
        self.duration = duration # in seconds, may be float
        self.f = freq            # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

    def run(self) :
        self.samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(self.fs*self.duration)*self.f/self.fs)).astype(np.float32)
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                              channels=1,
                              rate=self.fs,
                              output=True)
        self.stream.write(self.volume*self.samples)
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()


duration = 5
tones = [
    {'frequency': 100, 'volume': .8},
    {'frequency': 200, 'volume': .6},
    {'frequency': 500, 'volume': .4},
]
for tone in tones:
    WavePlayerLoop(tone['frequency'], tone['volume'], duration).start()
```